# What is wrong with my Javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I/m trying to make a health calculator  ( a small project web app for learning) and I am kind of stuck here with this function bellow. What I want it to do is : get the value from the form (age) and then return a statment if somebody is between 1-10 or between 15-20 another statement and so on. Could anyone help please?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> HEALTH APP</title>

    <script language="JavaScript">
  <!--
  function calculateAge() {
  var age = document.ageForm.age.value
  if(age < 1){
  document.ageForm.meaning.value = "your a baby, keep growing."
  }
  if(age > 20 && age < 30){
  document.ageForm.meaning.value = "Your young, no risk here"
  }
  if(age > 31 && age < 40){
  document.ageForm.meaning.value = "Check your diet"
  }
  if(age > 50){
  document.ageForm.meaning.value = "Risky"
  }
  }
  else{
  alert("Please Fill in everything correctly")
  }
  }
  //-->
  </script>

  </head>
  <body>

  <form name="ageForm">
  Your age (years): <input type="text" name="age" size="10"><br />
  <input type="button" value="Show explanation " onClick="calculateAge()"><br />
  Explenation: <input type="text" name="meaning" size="25"><br />
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
  </form>




  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Tadej, welcome to StackOverflow! Firstly, that's not how you access any element from your JavaScript code. See this guide by DigitalOcean for more info: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-access-elements-in-the-dom Secondly, the way you've defined your conditional statements are invalid. Check out the guide by Alligator.io for more info: https://alligator.io/js/if-statements/

Comment: You have "}" at line 14. Delete it )

Comment: The answers below allow your function to 'work' - but don't forget about people who are 40 to 49 as at the moment your form won't work for them! Also it's `you're` (sorry had to be a grammar nazi!)

Comment: haha @David, we should include a 'closed as the intended behaviour of the function discriminates middle-aged people in perfect health and encourages the extinction of certain age groups' option! (kidding!)

Comment: Next time please tell us what you're seeing (what goes wrong, what error you get, and so on). Also, `age` is a string so you're relying on implicit conversions when comparing that to numbers, and for numbers you're not handling 2 thru 20, 30, 31, and 40 thru 50 —not just 40 to 49, @Graham ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two problems :

- there is a wrong '}' before 'else' statment.
- You should use else if or switch case instead of if()

Here is Corrected code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> HEALTH APP</title>

    <script language="JavaScript">
  <!--
  function calculateAge() {
  var age = document.ageForm.age.value
  if(age < 1){
  document.ageForm.meaning.value = "your a baby, keep growing."
  }
  else if(age > 20 && age < 30){
  document.ageForm.meaning.value = "Your young, no risk here"
  }
  else if(age > 31 && age < 40){
  document.ageForm.meaning.value = "Check your diet"
  }
  else if(age > 50){
  document.ageForm.meaning.value = "Risky"
  }
  else{
  alert("Please Fill in everything correctly")
  }
  }
  //-->
  </script>

  </head>
  <body>

  <form name="ageForm">
  Your age (years): <input type="text" name="age" size="10"><br />
  <input type="button" value="Show explanation " onClick="calculateAge()"><br />
  Explenation: <input type="text" name="meaning" size="25"><br />
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
  </form>




  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My comment to Sonu's later/accepted answer applies here too.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way. There are 2 issues with your code, 1 is `}` and other is you are only using `if` and `else` only for the last if. So if age is less than 50 it will show alert with the input value update as well. So prefer `if{}elseif(){}`

```
function calculateAge() {
        var age = document.ageForm.age.value
        if (age < 1) {
            document.ageForm.meaning.value = "your a baby, keep growing."
        }else if (age > 20 && age < 30) {
            document.ageForm.meaning.value = "Your young, no risk here"
        } else if (age > 31 && age < 40) {
            document.ageForm.meaning.value = "Check your diet"
        }else if (age > 50) {
            document.ageForm.meaning.value = "Risky"
        } else {
            alert("Please Fill in everything correctly")
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Tadej, now try with 2 thru 20, 30, 31, and 40 thru 50... Also, for most of the `if`s I'd really not use `(age > min && age < max)`, instead I'd only use `(age < max)` (or `<= max`) to get implicit ranges, where the lower boundary is already defined in the earlier `if`. Also, I'd use some type checking to ensure the input is numeric.

Answer (score -1):

follow below code.

```
function calculateAge() {
        var age = document.ageForm.age.value
        if (age < 1) {
            document.ageForm.meaning.value = "your a baby, keep growing."
        }
        if (age > 20 && age < 30) {
            document.ageForm.meaning.value = "Your young, no risk here"
        }
        if (age > 31 && age < 40) {
            document.ageForm.meaning.value = "Check your diet"
        }
        if (age > 50) {
            document.ageForm.meaning.value = "Risky"
        } else {
            alert("Please Fill in everything correctly")
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the age is less that 51, it shows an alert. You should use else ifs instead of ifs